# How to stop Laravel request from getting manipulated using Burp tool?

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-5.8, burp

My tester has integrated Burp tool with firefox, where he is running our project on same browser. He is saving each and every request of application in Burp tool and then login with another user to post request data of first user, or he logout of system and only post request data where he is able to save that data properly. Can anybody please answer that how I can stop laravel to save data on Burp or any other tool like this

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: yes, my tester has reported it as security issue with laravel.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski : Can you please address this problem?

Comment: I just verified it again  and it's nopt an issue.. After session logout no one can manipulate request data...  I am closing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an integral part of testing. You should not be trying to find ways to deceive testing tools. You should be implementing good security in your application.

Comment: Yes I have added this question to add laravel security accordingly. I don't want to deceive any testing tool.